# Access embedded postgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, database-connectivity

Can an **embedded** postgreSQL 9.1.1 database be simultaneously accessed externally by another application?

I installed a separate postgreSQL server on the same machine, but the embedded database doesn't seems to be visible.

The other problem is that I cant find out the password for the user that the application is using to connect to its internal database file.

Comment: First of all - the postgres DB can not be embedded. It allways is a standalone server.

Comment: Define embedded, Igor is correct in what he says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to connect to a postgresql server, that was installed on you machine by some software you need:

1) Find the cluster directory of the installed postgresql server.

2) Search for the postgresql.conf file in cluster directory. There you will find a port, the server is listening to.

3) Search for pg_hba.conf file in cluster directory. Adding `host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust` line to this conf file will allow you to access the server without password.

4) Start the postgres server, specifying the cluster directory from step 1 . (Search for postgres binaryes, installed by the application.). If it is already running - you need to restart it.

5) Connect to the DB using post from step 2 and any postgres login (Try login `postgres` it is a default one)